# ¿Cómo agregar otro campo en la misma variable?

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

Estoy haciendo un modelo nuevo en el módulo de *odoo* que estoy ocupando pero tengo duda con la estructura ya que hay 2 campos que tienen dos espacios para el registro. ¿Cómo podría? o ¿Qué tendría que agregar en el modelo? para que existan dos campos ya que se supone que en el primer campo se ingresan números y en el segundo en automático el nombre de lo que viene ligado a esos números

Adjunto código:

````
from odoo import fields, api, models


 class Bascula (models.Model):

_name = ('mti_bascula')

Proovedor = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='res.partner.category',
    String = 'Proovedor'
    
)
Operador = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='res.partener.categoy',
    String = 'Operador'
)
Remitente = fields.Char(String='Remitente')
Carta_porte = fields.Integer(String='Carta_porte')
Destino = fields.Char(string="Destino")
Via = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Aereo', 'Aereo'),
    ('Maritimo', 'Maritimo'),
    ('Terrestre', 'Terrestre')
])
Recibe = fields.Char(string="Recibe")
Ejecutivo = fields.Char(string="Ejecutivo")
Mercancia = fields.Char(string="Mercancia")
Peso_bruto = fields.Integer(string="Peso")```
````

Este es el código del modelo que estoy haciendo, no sé si eso que quiero hacer lo deba de poner en el modelo o en el *XML*.

Adjunto imagen de estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que así se debe de ver pero en base a *odoo* en la parte de carta porte y consignado como le podría agregar ese otro campo.

Comment: De que campo estas hablando?

Comment: los nombres de los campos osea solo esta para escribir pero no tienen ningun nombre aunque si les puse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas cambiar un campo en función de otro, puedes utilizar `@api.onchange('mi_campo_a_cambiar')`:

```js
@api.onchange('carta_porte')
def _onchange_carta_porte(self):
  for registro in self:
      valor_carta_porte = registro.carta_porte
      # Aqui va la lógica que quieras cambiar
      # ...
```

Comment: que estilos le tendria que dar a la vista para que este igual a la de la imagen?

Comment: Los campos simples se pueden acomodar con la etiqueta `group`. Para la tabla, necesitas utilzar un campo `Many2many` y dentro del field, definir su vista `tree`. Puedes realizar otra pregunta si lo requieres. El tema es un poco complejo.